# Examples/Textbooks on amortized analysis of algorithms

Tags: reference-request, big-list, amortized-analysis

I am trying to get the amortized analysis for a complicated algorithm. I am wondering whether there are textbooks or illustrative examples that could serve as inspiration of techniques in amortized analysis.

Comment: Check out Jeff Erickson's notes on algorithms. http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the classic papers by  Robert Tarjan and others:

- ["The Amortized Computational Complexity"](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/Amortized.pdf) by Robert Tarjan on a survey of amortized analysis of several algorithms and data structures.
- ["Amortized Efficiency Of List Update and Paging Rules"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/amortized-efficiency.pdf) by Daniel Sleator and Robert Tarjan on self-organizing lists.
- ["Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf) by Daniel Sleator and Robert Tarjan on splay trees.
- ["Efficiency of a Good But Not Linear Set Union Algorithm"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.437.8198&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Robert Tarjan on disjoint-set data structures.
- ["Fibonacci Heaps and Their Uses in Improved Network
  Optimization Algorithms"](http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Fibonacci-Heap-Tarjan.pdf) by Michael Fredman and Robert Tarjan on Fibonacci heaps.

The textbook [CLRS: Introduction to Algorithms; 3rd edition](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition) also contains chapters on Fibonacci heaps (Chapter 19) and Disjoint-set data structures (Chapter 21).

I also find the lecture note ["Amortized Analysis Explained"](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~fiebrink/423/AmortizedAnalysisExplained_Fiebrink.pdf) by Rebecca Fiebrink at Princeton University very helpful. It contains basic examples, in-depth examples, and some more involved examples.

Answer (score 1):

For textbook references an interesting article is as follows:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-5-amortized-analysis-introduction/

I can also refer to one recent paper which is very simple involving a straightforward application of amortized analysis:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01823